# Server side filtering of spark-cassandra on PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, cassandra, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to Spark and want to know more about its operation when cooperating with Cassandra.

I have been reminded to do server side filtering in most of the tutorials and I totally understand the importance of doing so.

Yet those tutorials either based on the Scala or `pyspark_cassandra`, and none of them are using PySpark.

Just curious if the following scriptlet is doing server side filtering or not.

Given a SparkConf object `conf`:

```
sc = pyspark.SparkContext(conf=conf)

sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
df = (sqlContext.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
    .options(keyspace="ks", table="tbl").load())

df.filter("id = 1234").show()
```

In addition, did I load the entire table to my spark cluster to do filtering in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cassandra connector supports predicate pushdown on Spark `DataFrames` so as long as pushdown is enabled you can safely assume that basic filters are executed on the Cassandra side. It may be not for complex predicates. If you're in doubt it is always best to check [`BasicCassandraPredicatePushDown` docstrings](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/v1.6.0-M1/spark-cassandra-connector/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/cassandra/BasicCassandraPredicatePushDown.scala#L6).

You can also check execution plan (`explain`). If predict is pushed-down it should be listed in `PushedFilters` section for example:

```py
df = (sqlContext
  .read
  .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
  .options(table="words", keyspace="test")
  .load())

df.select("word").where(col("word") == "bar").explain()
## == Physical Plan ==
## Scan org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraSourceRelation@62738171[word#0] 
## ... PushedFilters: [EqualTo(word,bar)]
```

In Spark 1.6 the PushedFilters explanation is a little misleading. It will list all filters that the datasource has been shown but won't actually tell you which ones the datasource used. In this case it's best to just see if `explain` plan has a seperate filter step for the predicate. If it does than the connector did not pushdown the predicated. If it didn't, then the predicate was pushed.

Another option is to turn on INFO/DEBUG logging for the Spark Cassandra Connector to see exactly what the Connector is doing in Catalyst

Comment: I'd just like to note that on Spark 1.6, the PushedFilters explanation is misleading. It will list all filters that the datasource can see and won't actually tell you which ones are actually pushed. In this case it's best to just see if spark did a separate "Filter" step outside of the Datasource. If it didn't, then the predicate was pushed. Also you can turn on INFO/DEBUG logging for the connector to see exactly what the Connector is doing in Catalyst.